# docker-compose complete the build but get a "Connection to localhost:5432 refused" in the terminal when the API try start

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, docker-desktop

I'm unable to get my Angular project working on Docker-Desktop for the last two days (it was working fine three weeks ago!)

I got a Front-end (web) & Back-end (API) with a PostgreSQL database.

Back-end `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM openjdk:17.0.1-jdk-slim
WORKDIR /app
ADD target/prj-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar prj.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "prj.jar"]
```

Frontend `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:16.17.0-bullseye-slim as builder
LABEL desc="PRJ"
WORKDIR /app
COPY ["package.json","package-lock.json","/app/"]
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install curl -y && apt-get install nano -y
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
COPY . /app
RUN ng build
CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200
```

Docker-compose file

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  ### FRONTEND ###
  web:
    container_name: prj-web
    restart: always
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    depends_on:
      - "api"
    networks:
      customnetwork:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.12

  ### BACKEND ###
  api:
    container_name: prj-api
    restart: always
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - "2022:2022"
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    networks:
      customnetwork:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.11

  ### DATABASE ###
  db:
    container_name: prj-db
    restart: always
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    networks:
      customnetwork:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.10

networks:
  customnetwork:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16
          gateway: 172.20.0.1
```

This was working fine when I did a `docker-compose up -d`. Got a stack with the 3 containers running and project was available in my browser through localhost:4200

What I did during the 3 weeks was just adding components in the Front-end. I did not change anything neither in the Back-end nor in the config files...

If I run the web and the DB in Docker-Desktop and I compile the Back-end in my IDE (Intellij) the apps is working my API interact with the DB and WEB container from Docker-Desktop.

I can connect to my PostgreSQL DB from DBeaver on Windows without problem.
It seems that the API can't access the DB inside Docker-Desktop.

Find several things about that specific issue, change the

```
spring.datasource.url           = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
```

to

```
spring.datasource.url           = jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/postgres
```

But by doing this I can't run a

```
./mvnw clean package
```

command, got an error during the build as it can't connect to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally i found the solution!

To avoid any error during the `./mvnw clean package` i added `-DskipTests` and changed the spring datasource from

`spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres`
to
`spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/postgres`

and problem solved!